# (Linux/X11) Transparent opengl object on transparent window with solid background shows what's behind the window

Tags: c, linux, opengl, transparency, x11

On Linux with X11, I modified a [datenwolf's piece of code](https://github.com/datenwolf/codesamples/blob/master/samples/OpenGL/x11argb_opengl/x11argb_opengl.c) to draw a transparent cube on a transparent window with a solid background.

Here is the code :

```
/*------------------------------------------------------------------------
 * A demonstration of OpenGL in a  ARGB window
 *    => support for composited window transparency
 *
 * (c) 2011 by Wolfgang 'datenwolf' Draxinger
 *     See me at comp.graphics.api.opengl and StackOverflow.com

 * License agreement: This source code is provided "as is". You
 * can use this source code however you want for your own personal
 * use. If you give this source code to anybody else then you must
 * leave this message in it.
 *
 * This program is based on the simplest possible
 * Linux OpenGL program by FTB (see info below)

  The simplest possible Linux OpenGL program? Maybe...

  (c) 2002 by FTB. See me in comp.graphics.api.opengl

  --
  <\___/>
  / O O \
  \_____/  FTB.

------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
#define _GNU_SOURCE

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

#include <sys/types.h>
#include <time.h>

#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <GL/glx.h>
#include <GL/glxext.h>
#include <X11/Xatom.h>
#include <X11/extensions/Xrender.h>
#include <X11/Xutil.h>

#define USE_CHOOSE_FBCONFIG

static void fatalError(const char *why)
{
  fprintf(stderr, "%s", why);
  exit(0x666);
}

static int Xscreen;
static Atom del_atom;
static Colormap cmap;
static Display *Xdisplay;
static XVisualInfo *visual;
static XRenderPictFormat *pict_format;
static GLXFBConfig *fbconfigs, fbconfig;
static int numfbconfigs;
static GLXContext render_context;
static Window Xroot, window_handle;
static GLXWindow glX_window_handle;
static int width, height;

static int VisData[] = {
GLX_RENDER_TYPE, GLX_RGBA_BIT,
GLX_DRAWABLE_TYPE, GLX_WINDOW_BIT,
GLX_DOUBLEBUFFER, True,
GLX_RED_SIZE, 8,
GLX_GREEN_SIZE, 8,
GLX_BLUE_SIZE, 8,
GLX_ALPHA_SIZE, 8,
GLX_DEPTH_SIZE, 16,
None
};

static int isExtensionSupported(const char *extList, const char *extension)
{

  const char *start;
  const char *where, *terminator;

  /* Extension names should not have spaces. */
  where = strchr(extension, ' ');
  if ( where || *extension == '\0' )
    return 0;

  /* It takes a bit of care to be fool-proof about parsing the
     OpenGL extensions string. Don't be fooled by sub-strings,
     etc. */
  for ( start = extList; ; ) {
    where = strstr( start, extension );

    if ( !where )
      break;

    terminator = where + strlen( extension );

    if ( where == start || *(where - 1) == ' ' )
      if ( *terminator == ' ' || *terminator == '\0' )
        return 1;

    start = terminator;
  }
  return 0;
}

static Bool WaitForMapNotify(Display *d, XEvent *e, char *arg)
{
  return d && e && arg && (e->type == MapNotify) && (e->xmap.window == *(Window*)arg);
}

static void describe_fbconfig(GLXFBConfig fbconfig)
{
  int doublebuffer;
  int red_bits, green_bits, blue_bits, alpha_bits, depth_bits;

  glXGetFBConfigAttrib(Xdisplay, fbconfig, GLX_DOUBLEBUFFER, &doublebuffer);
  glXGetFBConfigAttrib(Xdisplay, fbconfig, GLX_RED_SIZE, &red_bits);
  glXGetFBConfigAttrib(Xdisplay, fbconfig, GLX_GREEN_SIZE, &green_bits);
  glXGetFBConfigAttrib(Xdisplay, fbconfig, GLX_BLUE_SIZE, &blue_bits);
  glXGetFBConfigAttrib(Xdisplay, fbconfig, GLX_ALPHA_SIZE, &alpha_bits);
  glXGetFBConfigAttrib(Xdisplay, fbconfig, GLX_DEPTH_SIZE, &depth_bits);

  fprintf(stderr, "FBConfig selected:\n"
    "Doublebuffer: %s\n"
    "Red Bits: %d, Green Bits: %d, Blue Bits: %d, Alpha Bits: %d, Depth Bits: %d\n",
    doublebuffer == True ? "Yes" : "No",
    red_bits, green_bits, blue_bits, alpha_bits, depth_bits);
}

static void createTheWindow()
{
  XEvent event;
  int x,y, attr_mask;
  XSizeHints hints;
  XWMHints *startup_state;
  XTextProperty textprop;
  XSetWindowAttributes attr = {0,};
  static char *title = "FTB's little OpenGL example - ARGB extension by WXD";

  Xdisplay = XOpenDisplay(NULL);
  if (!Xdisplay) {
    fatalError("Couldn't connect to X server\n");
  }
  Xscreen = DefaultScreen(Xdisplay);
  Xroot = RootWindow(Xdisplay, Xscreen);

  fbconfigs = glXChooseFBConfig(Xdisplay, Xscreen, VisData, &numfbconfigs);
  fbconfig = 0;
  for(int i = 0; i<numfbconfigs; i++) {
    visual = (XVisualInfo*) glXGetVisualFromFBConfig(Xdisplay, fbconfigs[i]);
    if(!visual)
      continue;

    pict_format = XRenderFindVisualFormat(Xdisplay, visual->visual);
    if(!pict_format)
      continue;

    fbconfig = fbconfigs[i];
    if(pict_format->direct.alphaMask > 0) {
      break;
    }
  }

  if(!fbconfig) {
    fatalError("No matching FB config found");
  }

  describe_fbconfig(fbconfig);

  /* Create a colormap - only needed on some X clients, eg. IRIX */
  cmap = XCreateColormap(Xdisplay, Xroot, visual->visual, AllocNone);

  attr.colormap = cmap;
  attr.background_pixmap = None;
  attr.border_pixmap = None;
  attr.border_pixel = 0;
  attr.event_mask =
    StructureNotifyMask |
    EnterWindowMask |
    LeaveWindowMask |
    ExposureMask |
    ButtonPressMask |
    ButtonReleaseMask |
    OwnerGrabButtonMask |
    KeyPressMask |
    KeyReleaseMask;

  attr_mask =
  //  CWBackPixmap|
    CWColormap|
    CWBorderPixel|
    CWEventMask;

  width = DisplayWidth(Xdisplay, DefaultScreen(Xdisplay))/2;
  height = DisplayHeight(Xdisplay, DefaultScreen(Xdisplay))/2;
  x=width/2, y=height/2;

  window_handle = XCreateWindow(  Xdisplay,
          Xroot,
          x, y, width, height,
          0,
          visual->depth,
          InputOutput,
          visual->visual,
          attr_mask, &attr);

  if( !window_handle ) {
    fatalError("Couldn't create the window\n");
  }

#if USE_GLX_CREATE_WINDOW
  fputs("glXCreateWindow ", stderr);
  int glXattr[] = { None };
  glX_window_handle = glXCreateWindow(Xdisplay, fbconfig, window_handle, glXattr);
  if( !glX_window_handle ) {
    fatalError("Couldn't create the GLX window\n");
  }
#else
  glX_window_handle = window_handle;
#endif

  textprop.value = (unsigned char*)title;
  textprop.encoding = XA_STRING;
  textprop.format = 8;
  textprop.nitems = strlen(title);

  hints.x = x;
  hints.y = y;
  hints.width = width;
  hints.height = height;
  hints.flags = USPosition|USSize;

  startup_state = XAllocWMHints();
  startup_state->initial_state = NormalState;
  startup_state->flags = StateHint;

  XSetWMProperties(Xdisplay, window_handle,&textprop, &textprop,
      NULL, 0,
      &hints,
      startup_state,
      NULL);

  XFree(startup_state);

  XMapWindow(Xdisplay, window_handle);
  XIfEvent(Xdisplay, &event, WaitForMapNotify, (char*)&window_handle);

  if ((del_atom = XInternAtom(Xdisplay, "WM_DELETE_WINDOW", 0)) != None) {
    XSetWMProtocols(Xdisplay, window_handle, &del_atom, 1);
  }
}

static int ctxErrorHandler( Display *dpy, XErrorEvent *ev )
{
    fputs("Error at context creation", stderr);
    return 0;
}

static void createTheRenderContext()
{
  int dummy;
  if (!glXQueryExtension(Xdisplay, &dummy, &dummy)) {
    fatalError("OpenGL not supported by X server\n");
  }

#if USE_GLX_CREATE_CONTEXT_ATTRIB
  #define GLX_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION_ARB       0x2091
  #define GLX_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION_ARB       0x2092
  render_context = NULL;
  if( isExtensionSupported( glXQueryExtensionsString(Xdisplay, DefaultScreen(Xdisplay)), "GLX_ARB_create_context" ) ) {
    typedef GLXContext (*glXCreateContextAttribsARBProc)(Display*, GLXFBConfig, GLXContext, Bool, const int*);
    glXCreateContextAttribsARBProc glXCreateContextAttribsARB = (glXCreateContextAttribsARBProc)glXGetProcAddressARB( (const GLubyte *) "glXCreateContextAttribsARB" );
    if( glXCreateContextAttribsARB ) {
      int context_attribs[] =
      {
        GLX_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION_ARB, 3,
        GLX_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION_ARB, 0,
        //GLX_CONTEXT_FLAGS_ARB        , GLX_CONTEXT_FORWARD_COMPATIBLE_BIT_ARB,
        None
      };

      int (*oldHandler)(Display*, XErrorEvent*) = XSetErrorHandler(&ctxErrorHandler);

      render_context = glXCreateContextAttribsARB( Xdisplay, fbconfig, 0, True, context_attribs );

      XSync( Xdisplay, False );
      XSetErrorHandler( oldHandler );

      fputs("glXCreateContextAttribsARB failed", stderr);
    } else {
      fputs("glXCreateContextAttribsARB could not be retrieved", stderr);
    }
  } else {
      fputs("glXCreateContextAttribsARB not supported", stderr);
  }

  if(!render_context)
  {
#else
  {
#endif
    render_context = glXCreateNewContext(Xdisplay, fbconfig, GLX_RGBA_TYPE, 0, True);
    if (!render_context) {
      fatalError("Failed to create a GL context\n");
    }
  }

  if (!glXMakeContextCurrent(Xdisplay, glX_window_handle, glX_window_handle, render_context)) {
    fatalError("glXMakeCurrent failed for window\n");
  }
}

static int updateTheMessageQueue()
{
  XEvent event;
  XConfigureEvent *xc;

  while (XPending(Xdisplay))
  {
    XNextEvent(Xdisplay, &event);
    switch (event.type)
    {
    case ClientMessage:
      if (event.xclient.data.l[0] == del_atom)
      {
        return 0;
      }
    break;

    case ConfigureNotify:
      xc = &(event.xconfigure);
      width = xc->width;
      height = xc->height;
      break;
    }
  }
  return 1;
}

/*  6----7
   /|   /|
  3----2 |
  | 5--|-4
  |/   |/
  0----1

*/

GLfloat cube_vertices[][8] =  {
  /*  X     Y     Z   Nx   Ny   Nz    S    T */
  {-1.0, -1.0,  1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0}, // 0
  { 1.0, -1.0,  1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0}, // 1
  { 1.0,  1.0,  1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0}, // 2
  {-1.0,  1.0,  1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0}, // 3

  { 1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0}, // 4
  {-1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 1.0, 0.0}, // 5
  {-1.0,  1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 1.0, 1.0}, // 6
  { 1.0,  1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 1.0}, // 7

  {-1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0}, // 5
  {-1.0, -1.0,  1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0}, // 0
  {-1.0,  1.0,  1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0}, // 3
  {-1.0,  1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0}, // 6

  { 1.0, -1.0,  1.0,  1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0}, // 1
  { 1.0, -1.0, -1.0,  1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0}, // 4
  { 1.0,  1.0, -1.0,  1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0}, // 7
  { 1.0,  1.0,  1.0,  1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0}, // 2

  {-1.0, -1.0, -1.0,  0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0}, // 5
  { 1.0, -1.0, -1.0,  0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0}, // 4
  { 1.0, -1.0,  1.0,  0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0}, // 1
  {-1.0, -1.0,  1.0,  0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0}, // 0

  {-1.0, 1.0,  1.0,  0.0,  1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0}, // 3
  { 1.0, 1.0,  1.0,  0.0,  1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0}, // 2
  { 1.0, 1.0, -1.0,  0.0,  1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0}, // 7
  {-1.0, 1.0, -1.0,  0.0,  1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0}, // 6
};

static void draw_cube(void)
{
  glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
  glEnableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
  glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

  glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, sizeof(GLfloat) * 8, &cube_vertices[0][0]);
  glNormalPointer(GL_FLOAT, sizeof(GLfloat) * 8, &cube_vertices[0][3]);
  glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, sizeof(GLfloat) * 8, &cube_vertices[0][6]);

  glDrawArrays(GL_QUADS, 0, 24);
}

float const light0_dir[]={0,1,0,0};
float const light0_color[]={78./255., 80./255., 184./255.,1};

float const light1_dir[]={-1,1,1,0};
float const light1_color[]={255./255., 220./255., 97./255.,1};

float const light2_dir[]={0,-1,0,0};
float const light2_color[]={31./255., 75./255., 16./255.,1};

static void redrawTheWindow()
{
  float const aspect = (float)width / (float)height;

  static float a=0;
  static float b=0;
  static float c=0;

  glDrawBuffer(GL_BACK);

  glViewport(0, 0, width, height);

  // Clear with alpha = 0.0, i.e. full transparency
  glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
  glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

  glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
  glLoadIdentity();
  glFrustum(-aspect, aspect, -1, 1, 2.5, 10);

  glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
  glLoadIdentity();

  glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
  glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);

#if 0
  glEnable(GL_BLEND);
  glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
#endif

  glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, light0_dir);
  glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_DIFFUSE, light0_color);

  glLightfv(GL_LIGHT1, GL_POSITION, light1_dir);
  glLightfv(GL_LIGHT1, GL_DIFFUSE, light1_color);

  glLightfv(GL_LIGHT2, GL_POSITION, light2_dir);
  glLightfv(GL_LIGHT2, GL_DIFFUSE, light2_color);

  glTranslatef(0., 0., -5.);

  glRotatef(a, 1, 0, 0);
  glRotatef(b, 0, 1, 0);
  glRotatef(c, 0, 0, 1);

  glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);
  glEnable(GL_LIGHT1);
  glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);

  glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);
  glColorMaterial(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_AMBIENT_AND_DIFFUSE);

  glColor4f(1., 1., 1., 0.5);

  glCullFace(GL_FRONT);
  draw_cube();
  glCullFace(GL_BACK);
  draw_cube();

  a = fmod(a+0.1, 360.);
  b = fmod(b+0.5, 360.);
  c = fmod(c+0.25, 360.);

  struct timespec Ta, Tb;

  clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW, &Ta);
  glXSwapBuffers(Xdisplay, glX_window_handle);
  clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW, &Tb);

  // fprintf(stderr, "glXSwapBuffers returned after %f ms\n", 1e3*((double)Tb.tv_sec + 1e-6*(double)Tb.tv_nsec) - 1e3*((double)Ta.tv_sec + 1e-6*(double)Ta.tv_nsec));
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  createTheWindow();
  createTheRenderContext();

  glClearColor(0.,0.,0.,1.);

  while (updateTheMessageQueue()) {
    redrawTheWindow();
  }

  return 0;
}
```

You can build it with : 
    gcc -std=c99 -g3 -o x11argb_opengl -DUSE_GLX_CREATE_CONTEXT_ATTRIB=0 -DUSE_GLX_CREATE_WINDOW=0 x11argb_opengl.c -lX11 -lXrender -lGL -lm

This looks like :

[image: Rendering]

As you can see, the terminal window shows up through the cube while the background is solid (see `glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);` in the code) and we don't see the terminal in the rest of the window.
Adding another object behind the cude doesn't help.
For example, I tried to add :

```
glPushMatrix();
glTranslatef(0., 0., -3.);
glScalef(2.,2.,1.);
glColor4f(1., 0., 0., 1.);
glCullFace(GL_FRONT);
draw_cube();
glCullFace(GL_BACK);
draw_cube();
glPopMatrix();
```

between : `draw_cube();` and `b = fmod(b+0.5, 360.);` around line 463.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So what happens there is, that when the cube is drawn the alpha values written by the cube's fragments overwrite the "solid opaque" color of the clearing step and leave an alpha<1 behind. This usually happens if blending is disabled and less-than-1 alpha fragment colours are written.

In general when writing to a to-be-alpha-blended framebuffer you always want to add opacity (never subtract from it). To this end you need separable blending with the blend func for the alpha channel being GL_ONE for destination alpha (and whatever blend func you want for the RGB part).